# Scope of enum itself in Objective-C?

Tags: objective-c, enums, scope, c99

Consider the following code:

```
enum TableSections {
    kSection1 = 0,
    kSection2 = 1,
    };
```

What is the scope of the identifier `TableSections`?  If this code is in an implementation file, is `TableSections` only defined within that compilation unit, defined globally, or something else?

And is the answer specific to Objective-C (llvm, clang, etc.?) or general for all C99 or some larger set?

Comment: Note that neither Clang nor LLVM are themselves specific to ObjC. It's just that Apple has a large hand in the development of both the language and those tools. LLVM is a code generator that actually takes its own language (LLVM IR) as input. Clang is a front-end to LLVM that handles C, C++, ObjC, and ObjC++. Other languages can be parsed and translated before being passed off to LLVM.

Comment: @JoshCaswell: Good point.  I tend to forget where the line is between Clang and LLVM.  What I'd meant to get at was that there are language features specific to Clang and it seemed plausible (though perhaps not correct) that the answer might be specific to ObjC, to Clang, to C99, to C in general, or some other grouping or set along those lines.

Comment: I see -- it is certainly possible for the compiler to make a difference, but my sense is that those (mercifully) tend to be esoteric cases. Though there is stuff like the ObjC collection literal syntax that was designed hand-in-hand with Clang, but then again, nothing prevents GCC from being able to cope with it too.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Enums are C, so we're not talking about anything Objective-C specific.

---

Enums aren't involved in linkage. They're merely symbolic constants. They're defined wherever they're visible/accessible. If that's a compilation unit, then the enum is usable only from within that compilation unit of course (but not because it's `static`, local or anything else - simply because the compiler needs to see the source (textual definition) in order to be able to expand the enum members.